# How can I get the document meta data after saving a document in elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am saving documents to an index in Elasticsearch using the bulk API in a Python project. However, what I need is how can I return the created id of the document after this process?

```
success, failed = bulk(client, actions, refresh=True)

            result = {
                "success_count": success,
                "failed_count": len(failed),
                "success_data": actions if success == len(actions) else [],
                "failed_data": failed
            }
```

Comment: streaming bulk is working `for ok, document in streaming_bulk(client, actions=actions, index="test-index"):
    print(document["index"]["_id"])

`